# socket.io.js not found (404)

Tags: express, socket.io

I am referring to an issue that has been asked many times but the solutions posted elsewhere are not resolving my problem ie socket.io.js not found.

The error message is

> GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js 404

Any help would be appreciated.

I referenced socket.io.js in my JADE file:

```
script(src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js')
script(src='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js')
script(src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
script(src='/javascripts/sockets/client.js') // this is in public folder
```

In my App.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
io = require('socket.io');
http = require('http');
app = express();
server = http.createServer(app);
io = io.listen(server);


server.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
   console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

These are the versions I am using:

```
"express": "~4.13.1",
"jade": "~1.11.0",
"morgan": "~1.6.1",
"serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
"socket.io": "0.9.10"
```

Some additional info:
In my app.js: I referenced the server socket

```
// set up our socket server
require('./public/javascripts/sockets/server')(io);
```

'/javascripts/sockets/client.js' is my client socket:

```
var socket = io.connect('/');
socket.on('message', function (data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    $('#messages').append('<div class="'+data.type+'">' + data.message +
    '</div>');
});
$(function(){
    $('#send').click(function(){
    var data = {
        message: $('#message').val(),
        type:'userMessage'
    };
    socket.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    $('#message').val('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using the `socket.io` package for this as it is primarily intended to construct a socket.io server instance. Instead you should be using [`socket.io-client`](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client) which was specifically made to be used as the client socket.

I would recommend using `bower` to install this instead of `npm` as bower is made for front-end package management. Inside your project directory execute the following

**note:** If you don't have bower installed you'll need to install it globally `npm i -g bower`

```
bower init
bower install --save socket.io-client
```

Then you should make the `bower_components` directory created by installing the `socket.io-client` a static directory

`server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'bower_components')));`

Then change

`script(src='/javascripts/sockets/client.js') // this is in public folder`

to

`script(src='/bower_components/socket.io-client)`

Additionally, you're mixing your `server` and `app` variables. You should be using whatever variable your `socket.io` was created using, in this case you're using `server` so you should be using that. Your server file is mostly incorrect as you're instantiating many global values and you've created your `io` instance incorrectly.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'bower_components')));

server.listen(port, function(){
   console.log('Express server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

Comment: sorry, I think I need to provide more info. Please see above for extra info added.

Comment: (1) I think you meant io = require('socket.io').listen(server), it would return an error otherwise (2) I can't replace the my client.js file as all my codes are in there, instead I replaced src='/socket.io/socket.io.js with src='/bower_components/socket.io-client' but it returns file not found error so I change it to reference the socket.io.js file that's inside the folder instead but it return a transport polling 404 error.